# Data type of $1 vs. coalesce($1)

Tags: php, postgresql, query-string

This statement doesn't work with PostgreSQL 8.2.4 and PHP 5.2.17:

```
 pg_query_params('SELECT $1', array(1));
 ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1
```

Fair enough. This is a possible fix:

```
 pg_query_params('SELECT CAST($1 AS INTEGER)', array(1));
```

That makes sense since we're being explicit about the data type.

*But the following statement also works*, although it should be equivalent to the first expression:

```
 pg_query_params('SELECT COALESCE($1)', array(1));
```

Why? Does `COALESCE` somehow modify the data type of $1, or guarantee some simple data type as the result?

**Edit**: [The docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/functions-conditional.html#AEN13116) are rather short on the subject of `COALESCE`.

Comment: Assumably, yes. I would [check the docs of that function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-conditional.html#AEN15541). It should specify the return value - but don't ask me for an explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

`coalesce` always return the first non-null string,
in the event of all `null` (in your case, is undefined variable of `$1`) supplied,
it lead to `NULL`.

`NULL` is not truly same as undefined

*pardon my bad explanation ...*

The first example, you are trying to return a undefined variable which lead to an error.

However, in the third example, you are trying to return a NULL value (returned by coalesce),
there is no more undefined variable, just a NULL returned, this make *select work fine*

Comment: Do you have a reference for the last statement? A [NULL value](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) "indicate[s] that a data value does not exist in the database" and `COALESCE` is (according to the same page) "defined as shorthand for" the equivalent `CASE` statement, but `SELECT CASE WHEN $1 IS NOT NULL THEN $1 END` also fails.

Comment: `Since Null is not a member of any data domain, it is not considered a "value", but rather a marker (or placeholder) indicating the absence of value` from the doc you have supplied

Comment: How does that explain the difference between `NULL` and `undefined`? It seems to do the exact opposite: "not a value" === undefined. At least this is the interpretation used by [Perl](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/plperl-funcs.html): SQL `NULL` → Perl `undef`.